# Json string to list javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hey how can I convert json string into a list ?

```
[[1, 'group1', '#5bc6e1'], [2, 'group2', '#8ec936']]
```

I tried to use .split but it splited it wrong
I JSON.parse dont work because it has `'` and not `"`

Comment: If it has `'` instead of `"` then it is not JSON.

Comment: Just try to replace `'` to `"`, and then use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Where is this... "json"... coming from?

Comment: It's not valid JSON. It should be fixed _at source_ rather than tinkering around replacing the all the quotes.

Answer (score -3):

You can replace all single quotes with double quotes (with [`String.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)), then parse with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
const str = "[[1, 'group1', '#5bc6e1'], [2, 'group2', '#8ec936']]";
const result = JSON.parse(str.replaceAll("'", '"'));

console.log(result)
```